# Unable to access magento admin due to security reasons

Tags: magento2, xampp

The problem started here. Before checking any available installed ssl certificates, I configured base urls to ssl. From then onwards, while accessing my magento admin site, I get `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` error. I edited `core_config_data` columns `where path=where path like '%base%url%'` to set value to 0. Still I am not able to access the site.

How to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open you MySQL client

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' or path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

You will get a list of your URL's

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' or path = 'web/secure/base_url';
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                  | value                    |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|       496 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url | https://www.domain.com/ |
|       497 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url   | https://www.domain.com/ |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

Update the values you want like this

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://www.example.com/' where config_id in (496,497);
```

Where your config_id is the value's from the column under config_id

If you find that this value = 1 you should change it to 0

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'admin/url/custom';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the site url with http in core_config_data instead of 0 like
http://www.yourdomain.com/